# How to create a simple Expression tree for x=>x.List

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Can you please help me to build an expression tree for following code.

```
 class House
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}


class Room
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to pass `house=>house.Rooms` to a method with parameter of type `Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TValue>>> expression`. Need to know how to create an expression tree for this. In my actual project, I will be finding out the types of `House` and `Room` through reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building an expression consists of three parts:

- **Making parameters for passing an input to your expression** - you do it by calling [`Expression.Parameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355908%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, and passing it the type that you wish your expression parameter to receive.
- **Making expression body** - Use other methods of `Expression` class to construct an expression tree that describes your expression.
- **Combining parameters with the body** - Call one of the overloads of [`Expression.Lambda`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda(v=vs.110).aspx), passing it the desired delegate type.

In your case these steps would look like this:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(House), "h");
var body = Expression.Convert(
    Expression.Property(parameter, "Rooms")
,   typeof(IEnumerable<Room>)
);
var res = Expression.Lambda<Func<House,IEnumerable<Room>>>(body, parameter);
```

The body adds a cast expression to a property getter. You can use a different overload if the property has been discovered through reflection, and you have a `PropertyInfo` for it.

Comment: well explained Thanks!

Comment: If my requirement was to create tree for x=>x where x will be List<Room>. I will create parameter of typeof(IEnumerable<Room>). But how do i create body for it ?

Comment: @user3219798 for an expression `x=>x` the body would be the parameter itself if the types match, or `var body = Expression.Convert(parameter), typeof(IEnumerable<Room>))` if the types do not match.